# App is getting crash when i integrated and login through Gigya in social media

Tags: ios, facebook, google-plus, gigya

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.gigya.GigyaSDK:InvalidOperationException', reason: 'Already logged in, log out before attempting to login again'
*** First throw call stack:

Even I used [Gigya logout] prior to login statement in ios SDK, This issue happens when i try to login with facebook and Google plus

Answer (score 1):

Try logging out with the completionHandler instead:

```
[Gigya logoutWithCompletionHandler:^(GSResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    [Gigya loginToProvider:@"google" parameters:nil over:self completionHandler:^(GSUser *user, NSError *error) {
        // do stuff here
    }];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the engineers at Gigya. I would be happy to help you work through the issue you are facing but we need more to go on. My suggestion would be to send an email to support@gigya.com with this same description of your issue and ideally the xcode project so that we can look through it and see what exactly is the cause of the error. If you can get us the project then some code snippets might be helpful too.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Using the iOS API, how can I tell if the user is already logged in? I thought perhaps the [Gigya session] would be nil if that was the case, but doesn't appear to be right. Right now I'm just logging out before doing a login.

Comment: Does Gigya sign a Non Disclosure Agreement with the developer who is sending their intellectual property overseas?

Comment: Gigya does not share any intellectual property and Gigya would be happy to accommodate any NDA requirements set forth by the owner of the intellectual property in order to help with an integration.

Comment: @AaronBratcher, the best practice set forth by Gigya's R&D and Product teams are to use the `accounts.getAccountInfo` endpoint. A valid session will result in an error code of 0 along with user information while an invalid session will result in an error code of 403.